# stacked bar plot with error bars in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot a stacked bar plot with error bars. I have a data frame with five variables. Var1 contains the effects of treatments on three different species in `Var2`. The effects of treatments are given in variable `value`. Variable `start` and `end` contains the values for error bars. I want to plot a stacked bar plot in a way that orders of Var1 and Var2 should be same. Something like this:

[image]

This figure is just an example. Some example data:

```
Var1    Var2    value   start   end
Eff1    spe1    0.73    0.72    0.74
Eff2    spe1    0.25    0.24    0.26
Eff3    spe1    0.007   0.006   0.008
Eff1    spe2    0.69    0.68    0.7
Eff2    spe2    0   0   0
Eff3    spe2    0.3 0.29    0.31
Eff1    spe3    0.78    0.77    0.79
Eff2    spe3    0   0   0
Eff3    spe3    0.212   0.2 0.22
```

The values in table does not match to the figure above. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079064/placement-of-error-bars-in-barplot-using-ggplot2) may be helpful. Try your title in google, you get lot of answers :)

Comment: In your data frame, where is 'start' and 'end'?

Comment: The problem with error bars combined with stacked bar plot, is that the error bars will be ploted per each level of the stack bar, this is what you want? or you wan to aggregate them some how? you can see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213717/single-error-bar-on-stacked-bar-plot-ggplot

Comment: sorry, It is corrected now @ramesh

Comment: I want error bars for each level not the aggregate as in the other question you suggested @DavidArenburg

Comment: Ok, see below then, not sure when you want to place your error bars though

Comment: @DavidArenburg, something like that but error bars should be around the "value" values e.g. for spe1 there should be three error bars i.e. for Eff1 the error bars should be between 0.72 and 0.74, for Eff2 around 0.24 and 0.26 and for Eff3 between 0.006 and 0.008

Comment: That's exactly where the error bars are... Let me viusalize it a bit better

Comment: See my edited answer, I've also added `dodge` so they wont evoerlap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- read.table(text="
Var1    Var2    value   ybegin  yend
Eff1    spe1    0.73    0.72    0.74
Eff2    spe1    0.25    0.24    0.26
Eff3    spe1    0.007   0.006   0.008
Eff1    spe2    0.69    0.68    0.7
Eff2    spe2    0   0   0
Eff3    spe2    0.3 0.29    0.31
Eff1    spe3    0.78    0.77    0.79
Eff2    spe3    0   0   0
Eff3    spe3    0.212   0.2 0.22", header = T)
str(df)

df[df$Var1 == "Eff2", "ybegin"] <- df[df$Var1 == "Eff2", "ybegin"] + df[df$Var1 == "Eff1", "value"]
df[df$Var1 == "Eff2", "yend"] <- df[df$Var1 == "Eff2", "yend"] + df[df$Var1 == "Eff1", "value"]
df[df$Var1 == "Eff3", "ybegin"] <- df[df$Var1 == "Eff3", "ybegin"] + df[df$Var1 == "Eff2", "ybegin"]
df[df$Var1 == "Eff3", "yend"] <- df[df$Var1 == "Eff3", "yend"] + df[df$Var1 == "Eff2", "yend"]

library(ggplot2)
dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.9)
cols <- c("black", "white", "darkgrey") 
limits <- aes(ymax = yend , ymin = ybegin)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Var2, y = value, fill = Var1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", color = "black") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
  geom_errorbar(limits, colour = "red", width = 1,  position = dodge) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank() ,panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: How should we interpret this?

Comment: @PauloCardoso, Its just error bars per each Sep[i] per Eff[i]. I agrre it's hard to read because it's stacked, this is why I propoesed my other answer (see in comments), but the OP didn't want that

Comment: @PauloCardoso Cardoso and David Arenburg both of you right. I get the awnser according to my question. But I realized that ideally it would be nice to have error bars on top of each level.

Comment: yes, on top of each level would allow a better interpretation.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Could your answer be adjusted to relocate the error bars positions to the top of each level?

Comment: something like this but I could not able to do it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630506/error-bars-on-stacked-bar-ggplot2

Comment: @PauloCardoso, see my edit above. Added `dodge` so won't overlap

Comment: Yes, this seems to be effectively more correct. May not be the best data set to show it. Maybe dodging it would be better. Thank you David.

Comment: @mariariaz, if your levels are not overlaping in the real data set, you can remove the `, position = dodge` form `geom_errorbar` and you probably will get nicer plot like in the link you've attached

Comment: @DavidArenburg thank you for the suggestion yes, I will do that and plots are much nicer.

Comment: @mariariaz, You can also take the `+ scale_fill_manual(values = cols)` out if you want your plot to be colorful and not black and white like in your original question

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, a stacked barplot with errorbars isn't the best choice. For comparison an example with a dodged barplot with errorbars:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Var2, y=value, fill=Var1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position=position_dodge(width = 0.9)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=yend, ymin=ybegin), width=0.6, position=position_dodge(width = 0.9)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

which results in:
[image]