# Why are my error bars on my graph out of place?

Tags: r, ggplot2, png, gridextra

I have a graph that I'm trying to make with `ggplot` and `gridExtra`, but my error bars are out of place. I want the error bars to be at the top of each bar, not where they are now. What can I do to correct them?

Also, what `ggsave` parameters will generate a graph with the same pixel parameters that I am using with the r `png` base function? ggsave seems to work more consistently than this function, so I need to use it.

Data:

```
###Open packages###
library(readxl)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

#Dataframes
set1 <- data.frame(type = c(1,
                            1,
                            1,
                            1,
                            1,
                            1,
                            1,
                            1,
                            1,
                            2,
                            2,
                            2,
                            2,
                            2,
                            2,
                            2,
                            2,
                            2,
                            3,
                            3,
                            3,
                            3,
                            3,
                            3,
                            3,
                            3,
                            3),
                   flowRate = c(24,
                                24,
                                24,
                                45,
                                45,
                                45,
                                58,
                                58,
                                58,
                                24,
                                24,
                                24,
                                45,
                                45,
                                45,
                                58,
                                58,
                                58,
                                24,
                                24,
                                24,
                                45,
                                45,
                                45,
                                58,
                                58,
                                58),
                   speed = c(0.563120137230256,
                             0.301721535875508,
                             0.170683367727845,
                             0.698874950490133,
                             0.158488731250147,
                             0.162788814307903,
                             0.105943103772245,
                             0.682354871986346,
                             0.17945825301837,
                             0.806637519498752,
                             0.599304186634932,
                             0.268788206619179,
                             0.518615600601962,
                             0.907628477211427,
                             0.144209408332705,
                             0.161586044320138,
                             0.946354993801663,
                             0.488881557759483,
                             0.497120443885793,
                             0.666120238846602,
                             0.264813203831783,
                             0.717007333314455,
                             0.95119232422312,
                             0.833669574933742,
                             0.450082932184122,
                             0.309570971522678,
                             0.732874401666482))

set2 <- data.frame(type = c(1,
                            1,
                            1,
                            1,
                            1,
                            1,
                            1,
                            1,
                            1,
                            2,
                            2,
                            2,
                            2,
                            2,
                            2,
                            2,
                            2,
                            2,
                            3,
                            3,
                            3,
                            3,
                            3,
                            3,
                            3,
                            3,
                            3),
                   flowRate = c(24,
                                24,
                                24,
                                45,
                                45,
                                45,
                                58,
                                58,
                                58,
                                24,
                                24,
                                24,
                                45,
                                45,
                                45,
                                58,
                                58,
                                58,
                                24,
                                24,
                                24,
                                45,
                                45,
                                45,
                                58,
                                58,
                                58),
                   speed = c(0.489966876244169,
                             0.535542121502899,
                             0.265940150225231,
                             0.399521957817437,
                             0.0831661276630631,
                             0.302201301891001,
                             0.78194419406759,
                             0.202331797255324,
                             0.192182716686147,
                             0.163038660094618,
                             0.658020173938572,
                             0.735633308902771,
                             0.480982144690572,
                             0.749452781972296,
                             0.491759702396918,
                             0.459610541236644,
                             0.397660083986082,
                             0.939983924945833,
                             0.128956722185581,
                             0.998492083119223,
                             0.440514184126494,
                             0.242917958355044,
                             0.350643319960552,
                             0.02613674288471,
                             0.71625407018877,
                             0.589325978787179,
                             0.649116781211748))
```

Code:

```
#Standard error of the mean function
sem <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))

#Aggregate dataframes, mean and Standard Error
mean_set1 <- aggregate(set1, by=list(set1$flowRate, set1$speed), mean)
mean_set1 <- select(mean_set1, -Group.1, -Group.2)
mean_set1 <- arrange(mean_set1, type, flowRate)
sem_set1 <- aggregate(set1, by=list(set1$flowRate, set1$speed), sem)
sem_set1 <- as.data.frame(sem_set1)
sem_set1 <- cbind(mean_set1$type, mean_set1$flowRate, sem_set1$Group.2)
sem_set1 <- as.data.frame(sem_set1)


mean_set2 <- aggregate(set2, by=list(set2$flowRate, set2$speed), mean)
mean_set2 <- select(mean_set2, -Group.1, -Group.2)
mean_set2 <- arrange(mean_set2, type, flowRate)
sem_set2 <- aggregate(set2, by=list(set2$flowRate, set2$speed), sem)
sem_set2 <- as.data.frame(sem_set2)
sem_set2 <- cbind(mean_set2$type, mean_set2$flowRate, sem_set2$Group.2)
sem_set2 <- as.data.frame(sem_set2)



#Graph sets
set1_graph <- ggplot(mean_set1, aes(x=type, y=speed, fill=factor(flowRate)))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.6, position="dodge", col="black")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Flow Rate")+
  xlab("type")+ylab("Speed")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= mean_set1$speed,ymax=mean_set1$speed+sem_set1$V3), width=0.2, position = position_dodge(0.6))

set2_graph <- ggplot(mean_set2, aes(x=type, y=speed, fill=factor(flowRate)))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.6, position="dodge", col="black")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Speed")+
  xlab("type")+ylab("Flow Rate")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= mean_set2$speed,ymax=mean_set2$speed+sem_set2$V3), width=0.2, position = position_dodge(0.6))

#Grid.arrange and save image
png("image.png", width = 1000, height = 700)
grid.arrange(set1_graph, set2_graph,nrow=1, ncol=2)
dev.off()
```

Comment: You have mulitple values for a single set of (type, flowRate) in `mean_set1` e.g. for `type=1` & `flowRate=24` there are three values of speed: (0.17, 0.3, 0.56). I expect it is plotting each bar but the biggest is showing. As its a mean set, should this just be one value rather than three. My other note is this line `ymax=mean_set1$speed+sem_set1$V3`. My advice is bind the two data sets together and then use the variable names e.g. `speed+V3`. Else it may struggle with the groupings

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603380/how-to-organize-error-bars-to-relevant-bars-in-a-stacked-bar-plot-in-ggplot/58604197#58604197). You might find the solution applicable to solve your problem.